# If a permutation has no inversion, what is its parity?

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations

If a permutation has no inversion what is its parity?
I would assume it is $1$, because $\text{sgn}(\sigma)=(-1)^0=1$. Is this correct?

Comment: What does it mean 'has no inversion'? are we talking about permutation of finite or infinite elements?

Comment: For example $\sigma = (1,2,3,4)$ has no inversion. Just finite elements

Comment: If a permutation has no inversions then it is the identity.

Comment: If a permutation, $\sigma$, has even parity, then $\sigma^2=\text{id}$. Which means $\sigma$ itself is its own inverse.

Comment: @Exodd Maybe you're confusing inverse and inversion, because I am talking about this: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics) (or I am confused)

Comment: @Exodd Inversions, not inverse. It is another thing entirely.

Comment: Ok, understood.. But then the only permutation without inversions is the identity, or I am still mistaken?